# Control Flow Graphs - find all linearly independent paths

Tags: graph-algorithm, control-flow-graph

I want to find all the possible linearly independent paths in a CFG.
As per my limited knowledge of algorithms, a CFG would essentially be a directed graph containing cycles.
The formula for cyclomatic complexity is simple.
I was wondering if there is way to get all the linearly independent paths from the start to the end node (given by the cyclomatic complexity)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a recursive function from starting node with an iteration for each connected node (not present in the passed previous path), that self recall each iteration passing the path, and return all the complete paths only it meet the end node.